# Ugly Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $$y=\frac{ax^2}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)} + \frac{bx}{(x-b)(x-c)}+\frac{c}{x-c}+1$$
Then prove that $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}(\frac{a}{a-x}+\frac{b}{b-x}+\frac{c}{c-x})$$

What is the smartest way to solve this?

Comment: May be to solve the ODE...

Comment: But I don't think that reverse engineering will be appreciated in exam...

Comment: $$x-c$$ Should be there in first line .

Comment: yup a typing error occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\dfrac c{x-c}+1=\dfrac x{x-c}$$

$$\dfrac{bx}{(x-b)(x-c)}+\dfrac x{x-c}=x\cdot\dfrac{b+(x-b)}{(x-b)(x-c)}=\dfrac{x^2}{(x-b)(x-c)}$$

$$\frac{ax^2}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}+\dfrac{x^2}{(x-b)(x-c)}=x^2\cdot\frac{a+(x-a)}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}=\dfrac{x^3}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}$$

Now take logarithm in both sides and differentiate

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$$\frac{ax^2}{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)} + \frac{bx}{(x-b)(x-c)}+\frac{c}{c-x}=\dfrac A{x-a}+\dfrac B{x-b}+\dfrac C{x-c}$$

$$\implies ax^2+bx(x-a)+c(x-a)(x-b)=A(x-b)(x-c)+B(x-c)(x-a)+C(x-a)(x-b)$$

Compare the constants and the coefficients of $x,x^2$ to find $A,B,C$